# Generating fastQC report

Tags: r, fastq, rna-seq

I am using the `fastqcr` R package to generate a multi-qc and single-qc reports of fastq files for RNAseq analysis. While my mlti-qc report works fine, I am finding the following error while trying to generate a single-qc report from the fastqc results zipped file.

> Error in switch(status, PASS = "#00AFBB", WARN = "#E7B800", FAIL =
>   "#FC4E07") :  EXPR must be a length 1 vector

The code I am using is

**Step 6 - Building the final report**
It creates an HTML file containing FastQC reports of one or multiple samples.

```
#for multi-qc
qc_report(qc.dir, result.file = "F:/SUDI@UCSF01/COURSES/RNA seq Analysis/scRNA seq by R/My Tutorials/Made by Sudi/Trial Analysis files/FastQC/fastqc_results/multi_qc_report",
          experiment = "Exome sequencing of colon cancer cell lines", interpret = TRUE)

# For single-qc
qc.file1 <- "F:/SUDI@UCSF01/COURSES/RNA seq Analysis/scRNA seq by R/My Tutorials/Made by Sudi/Trial Analysis files/FastQC/fastqc_results/ERR522959_2_fastqc.zip"  
qc.file1

qc_report(qc.file1, result.file = "F:/SUDI@UCSF01/COURSES/RNA seq Analysis/scRNA seq by R/My Tutorials/Made by Sudi/Trial Analysis files/FastQC/fastqc_results/single_qc_report", interpret = TRUE, preview = TRUE)
```

Can somebody help me trouble shoot this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a version problem. Meaning that the scanning of the fastqc report depends on old versions and can't handle new ones. Just a guess. Because if you try to run

```
qc.file <- system.file("fastqc_results", "S1_fastqc.zip", package = "fastqcr")
qc_report(qc.file, result.file = "~/Desktop/result", interpret = TRUE)
```

This will work.

I am wondering what are the advantages of fastqcr, as MultiQC already have a very clear presentation of the data. And in the new versions of MultiQC you can also see an overview of failed and succeeded modules.